# UTF-16 Encoding appeding extra bytes

Tags: java, unicode

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class UnicodeConversion
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        String jaString = new String("\u20AC");
        System.out.println(jaString);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(jaString.getBytes("UTF-16")));
    }
}
```

In the UTF-16 encoding mechanism explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16
\u20AC (Euro Symbol) should take only single 16 bit char value, i.e 2 bytes. But I am seeing the output as 4 bytes

The output I receive is below

[-2, -1, 32, -84]

Could you explain me how the values -2 and -1 have come? I have run this with Jdk 11

Comment: Byte Order Mark. Use UTF-16BE if you don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

The first two bytes is a [Byte-Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) that determines the endianness of the 16-bit values.

`0xFE, 0xFF` = `-2, -1` meaning you've got Big-Endian byte order.

Use `"UTF-16LE"` or `"UTF-16BE"` instead to omit the BOM.